# Does Data's "copy constructor" copy its referenced bytes if inited with `freeWhenDone:false`?

Tags: swift

If I allocate a `Data` object with `bytesNoCopy:count:deallocator:.none`, it should reference the given bytes but in an unsafe manner, where I as programmer promise the bytes will be available during the lifetime of the Data, rather than Data controlling that on its own.

That's all fine. What I wonder is... Since it's a value type rather than a reference type, what happens when I assign another Data variable from my nocopy-Data? Does it COPY THE DATA (against my explicit wishes)? Or does it create one more unsafe Data instance which I must track the lifetime of, or risk crashes?

Here's an illustration:

```
let unsafe = malloc(5);
func makeUnsafeData() -> Data
{
    return Data(bytesNoCopy: unsafe, count: 5, deallocator: .none)
}

struct Foo
{
    var d: Data
}

var foo = Foo(d: makeUnsafeData())
free(unsafe)
```

The question is: does foo.d contain a dangling pointer to the freed bytes that used to be in `unsafe`? Or does it contain its own copy of those bytes, and is safe to use?

[This experiment gist](https://gist.github.com/nevyn-lookback/3839bd25998988348f49a914be9f8c9c) seems to indicate that NSData crashes in the above scenario, as expected, but Data does not; so my tentative conclusion is that Data copies the data, and there's no way to use a Data instance to transport bytes between functions without copying the bytes. But I'd love a reference to any documentation refuting or confirming this theory.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the answer is [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780455-init) after all... as long as all your Data instances are `let` and you don't mutate to it ever, ONLY the original bytes should be in memory, all Datas just referencing it.

I might just use NSData instead though since it's a reference type and less magic going on...

[image: Screenshot of documentation]